# MVVM View Model Organization

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, viewmodel

Making my first WPF MVVM application and I have a question about the organization of View Models. I have a ClassA with a one to many relationship with ClassB

[image: Class relationship]

I want the main view to look like this. It contains some info from class A along with a listview of all Class B instances that are associated with Class A

[image: Desired Main View]
I have come up with two approaches but I am unsure about which organization, if either, is considered the best approach. (This is a standard CRUD application: I want to be able to modify Class A, Add and remove Class B from Class A, modify Class B)

---

**Approach 1**
The main view model contains a ClassAViewModel and a List of ClassBViewModels

### [image: Approach 1]

**Approach 2**
The main view model contains a ClassAViewModel. The ClassAViewModel handels its own list of ClassBViewModels

### [image: Approach 2]

I would greatly appreciate any input on which approach will be best for me / a new approach. I'm also open to any recommendations of resources that would help me better understand software design and best practices in general

Comment: Look at your illustration for Approach 2 without any other knowledge and the relationship is immediately apparent. I cannot see what benefits Approach 1 should hold over Approach 2 - why are you even considering this? E.g. you want to be able to remove Class B from Class A, so it is beneficial when ClassBViewModel knows it's Parent ClassAViewModel (or vice-versa). 
It's also not a problem if two B's refer to the same model data.

Answer (score 0):

> The main view model contains a ClassAViewModel and a List of ClassBViewModels

No. The `ClassB` view models are only needed for views of `ClassB`, which is not what your main view is. Your main view will have a list (`ListBox` or `ItemsControl`) of the array of `ClassB` in your view model and templated to a user control that knows how to display them.

That user control then has its context as `ClassBViewModel` (only one) and handles the rest of the responsabilities for `ClassB` specifically.

> The main view model contains a ClassAViewModel. The ClassAViewModel handels its own list of ClassBViewModels

Again, no. At best you're confusing view models (the data necessary to display in the view your model types) and models (which correspond to the data itself). `AVM` links to an `A`, which links to a list of `B`, which, when bound to a view themselves, go through a `BVM` (if necessary).